# how to manipulate a string in php?

Tags: php, string

i have this situation:

```
 print_r($test);
 echo '<br>';
 $and = '';
 for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
     $and.= ' u.room = '.$test[$i];
     $and.= ' OR ';
 }
```

the result will be :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 ) 

u.room = 1 OR u.room = 3 OR u.room = 4 OR u.room = 5 OR u.room = 6 OR
```

what i want is to remove the last 'OR' so the string will become: `u.room = 1 OR u.room = 3 OR u.room = 4 OR u.room = 5 OR u.room = 6`

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
  $and.= ' u.room = '.$test[$i];

  if ($i != $count-1) {
    $and.= ' OR ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using another array works well, using [implode](http://php.net/implode) to produce the final string:

```
$clauses = array();
foreach($test as $t) {
   $clauses[] = "u.root = {t[$i]}";
}

$ands = implode(',', $clauses);
```

However, for your case, where it's one field and multiple values, you could go at it the other away:

```
$in = implode(',', $test);

$sql = " ... WHERE u.room IN ($in)";
```

Comment: Make sure all values in `$test` are properly escaped to avoid SQL injection attacks, though. If you're using MySQL, for example, do something like this: `$test = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $test);`

Answer (score 1):

Simpler (albeit not quite the same if `$test` is empty):

```
$and = "u.room = " . implode(" OR u.room = ", $test);
```